# mysql commandline option

Tags: mysql, linux, command-line

The commandline option -e or --execute in mysql is used to execute commands in shell prompt itself. Is there a way to print an error if the query was not successful (if the number if output is zero?)
Just like

```
Empty set (0.89 sec)
```

Comment: `Empty set (0.89)` is not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql` already prints out error messages by default. It also exits with an exit code larger than 0 if an error occured:

```
$ mysql -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version' THIS WON'T WORK"
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THIS WON'T WORK' at line 1
$ echo $?
1
$ mysql -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version'"
+---------------+------------+
| Variable_name | Value      |
+---------------+------------+
| version       | 5.5.19-log |
+---------------+------------+
$ echo $?
0
```